# XCode 9 missing CoreSimulator.framework

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have downloaded the new 9th version of XCode, and I have found out that there is no CoreSimulator.framework in the `~/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks`.

Using Xamarin Studio, I can run the app on the simulators, however, when trying to run tests, it is not successful since this framework is not present in this Xcode version.

I found out that in Xcode 8 the framework was present. Is there any possibility to import this framework to the new Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I must be grateful for @SushiHangover for the clue he gave.

I was using Visual Studio for Mac (version 7.1.xxx) and Xcode 9.4.2 previously and I recently updated both of them. So I have a Xamarin solution which I created using these old environment. Now I updated both of my tools to Xcode 10 and Visual Studio for Mac 7.6.2 and then tried running Xamarin.UITest on VS for Mac and then got an error like following:

```
SetUp : Calabash.XDB.Core.Exceptions.DeviceAgentException : Failed to launch simulator

ExitCode: 134
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4314243d __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6f053720 objc_exception_throw + 48
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6f056248 CALLING_SOME_+initialize_METHOD + 19
    11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6f04600c _class_initialize + 282
    12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6f045a19 lookUpImpOrForward + 238
    13  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6f045494 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
    14  iOSDeviceManager                    0x0000000103501fdf +[Device withID:] + 105
    15  iOSDeviceManager                    0x000000010350705e +[Command simulatorFromArgs:] + 227
    16  iOSDeviceManager                    0x0000000103513803 +[LaunchSimulatorCommand execute:] + 20
    17  iOSDeviceManager                    0x0000000103509285 +[CLI process:] + 1106
    18  iOSDeviceManager                    0x00000001034d69a1 main + 121
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff70121085 start + 1
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4315d08e +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff454f955d -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 194
    4   FBControlCore                       0x00000001035cc84b +[FBControlCoreFrameworkLoader loadPrivateFrameworksOrAbort] + 462
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6f056248 CALLING_SOME_+initialize_METHOD + 19
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6f04600c _class_initialize + 282
    7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6f045a19 lookUpImpOrForward + 238
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6f045494 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
    9   iOSDeviceManager                    0x000000010350db41 +[Simulator initialize] + 40
(
)
*** First throw call stack:
2018-10-22 09:23:08.055 iOSDeviceManager[1586:180576] *** Assertion failure in +[FBSimulatorControlFrameworkLoader loadPrivateFrameworksOrAbort], /Users/moody/git/calabash/FBSimulatorControl/FBControlCore/Utility/FBControlCoreFrameworkLoader.m:41
2018-10-22 09:23:08.058 iOSDeviceManager[1586:180576] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to private frameworks for FBSimulatorControl with error Error Domain=com.facebook.FBControlCore Code=0 "Attempting to load a file at path '/Applications/Xcode-10.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework', but it does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Attempting to load a file at path '/Applications/Xcode-10.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework', but it does not exist}'
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

So what I had to do is I just updated some of the available updates which was denoted in the Solutions Explorer panel as follows:

[image]

Right click on the Packages and update and then clean the solution and then try to re-run the UITests again and most probably it should be successfully run this time in all the platforms (in my case in the iPhone simulator and in Android simulator).

Hope this will be helpful to you all!

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 9 uses **`SimulatorKit.framework`** instead the older `CoreSimulator.framework`.

You need to update to the latest Visual Studio (Windows or Mac) as the *deprecated* Xamarin Studio is not going to support Xcode 9.

```
/Applications/Xcode9.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks
❯ tree
.
└── SimulatorKit.framework
    ├── Modules -> Versions/Current/Modules
    ├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
    ├── SimulatorKit -> Versions/Current/SimulatorKit
    └── Versions
        ├── A
        │   ├── Modules
        │   │   ├── SimulatorKit.swiftmodule
        │   │   │   ├── x86_64.swiftdoc
        │   │   │   └── x86_64.swiftmodule
        │   │   └── module.modulemap
        │   ├── Resources
        │   │   ├── CoreSimMetalLibrary.metallib
        │   │   ├── Info.plist
        │   │   ├── en.lproj
        │   │   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
        │   │   │   └── Localizable.strings
        │   │   └── version.plist
        │   ├── SimulatorKit
        │   └── _CodeSignature
        │       └── CodeResources
        └── Current -> A
```

Comment: Ok, that explains. But I am using the latest Visual Studio for Mac. And in tests it is still searching for the CoreSimulator. Should I explicitly stated somewhere to reference the SimulatorKit framework for Tests?

Comment: Tomkou, There are 2 possible ways to resolve your issue 
1) Make sure you have released version of xcode 9 not beta version. 
2) Run  the xcode 9 for once so that it can make some settings.

Comment: @tomkou In your question you state you are using `Xamarin Studio`... Other then @Zeeshan suggestions, make sure you are using the latest `Xamarin.iOS` version (`xamarin.ios-11.2.0.4.pkg`) to ensure you have the latest patches, the initial `xamarin.ios-11.0....` versions were still hardcoded to the `CoreSimulator.framework` in some areas.

Comment: Tried both of the suggestions, still the same issue occurs.

Comment: @tomkou What version of Xamarin.iOS do you have installed?